# GDS Unable to connect to database: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, looker-studio

Since this morning we're experiencing some problems in our Google Datastudio reports, connected through the MySQL connector. We are running MySQL8 through SSL and have not had any problems before. Unfortunately this morning some diagrams showed an error:

Unable to connect to database: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

It appears to be random what diagrams will get the error. When I try to refresh the data for a specific diagram by, for example, changing the date, it works again. Also, manually refreshing the report results in random broken diagrams.

Connections etc are all tested with external tools and seem to work fine.

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Having a similar issue with mysql from last few days.. no changes made on our end. Just something that started happening all of the sudden and refreshing the report sometimes fixes the problem, other times it stays as is.

Comment: Here is a forum link where a lot of other folks seems to be having the same issue https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/154939479/unable-to-connect-to-database-communications-link-failure?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

some users complains similar issue for few days on community forum
There is no status page that can confirm this and there is no channel support existing for GDS
https://support.google.com/datastudio/threads?hl=en&thread_filter=(category%3Aconnect_to_data)&max_results=20